# Get Midnight timestamp of a particular provided date

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a date which is say like this

```
$given_date = '2014-12-25'; //Y-m-d format
```

Now i want to get the midnight timestamp of the given date, so I am doing this method

```
$midnight = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$given_date).' 00:00:00');
```

Am I doing it right??

or I can use something like this?

```
$midnight = strtotime("midnight $given_date");
```

Which is better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert date and time to timestamp in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585632/how-to-convert-date-and-time-to-timestamp-in-php)

Comment: stop refering my answer as a duplicate one... its not... i wanted to know which one is better....

Answer (score 18):

I would prefer a more OO approach instead of fiddling around with strings:

```
$date = new DateTime($given_date);
$date->setTime(0,0,0);

// echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: `echo $date->getTimestamp();` OP wants the timestamp. But I still doesn't get the "is better". Faster ? Readable ?

Comment: @Debflav the "is better" in this approach is, that dates are handled as `DateTime` objects and not as strings and that the `DateTime` class gives more control on the calculation of dates and times. For me it's still unclear, which "midnight" is actually wanted, the next from now on or the past from a given date, which actually belongs to the day before. Running in to this, and probably some time zone issues as well and you end up in a mess with strings.

Comment: The "is better" was more for the OP. I'm agree with you and the use of DateTime object, maybe your explanation can be in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Using the static method createFromFormat from DateTime you can force the time-parts to be reset to 0 using '|':

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d|', $given_date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do it with:

```
list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $given_date);
$midnight = mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y);
```

Comment: And assuming the provided date is a timestamp, `$given_date` can be assigned this way : `$given_date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);`